# What is the expected sum of randomly picked k numbers from 1 to n?

Tags: probability

An urn contains $n$ balls numbered $1,2,...,n$. We remove $k$ balls at random and add up their numbers. Find the mean and variance of the total.

Comment: What have you tried with this so far, and where have you gotten stuck?

Comment: With or without replacement?

Comment: without replacement!!

Comment: @anomaly doesn't matter, the answer is the same either way.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Sure, but that may not be apparent a priori to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The $i$'th ball that you remove is equally likely to have been any of the originally available balls.

The random variable $X$ representing the sum of the balls you selected can be written as $X=X_1+X_2+X_3+\dots+X_k$ where $X_i$ is the random variable for the value of the $i$'th ball drawn.

Finally remember the linearity of expectation.

> $E[X]=E[X_1+X_2+\dots+X_k]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]+\dots+E[X_k]=kE[X_1]$ by symmetry

Comment: The balls are drawn without replacement. So $X_i$ are not iid.

Comment: @mathpadawan that doesn't matter in the slightest.  They might not be independent, but they *are* identically distributed otherwise.

Comment: I still don't understand why the expected value of  $X_i$'s are all the same. For example, if $X_1=2$($X_1$ could be 2 assuming we have more than 2 draws and more than 2 balls), then $X_2$ can't be 2 because $X_1$ already took the value 2. So in the calculation of the expected value, they would be different non?

Comment: @mathpadawan but you are forgetting to condition also on the possibility that it was *not* a $2$.  Why should the second ball be any more likely or less likely to be one result than another?

Comment: Ah! I think I understand now!

Answer (score 1):

OP also asked about the variance. The accepted answer doesn't say anything about the variance, which is a slightly more difficult problem, since $X_i$ are not iid. Nevertheless it can be calculated as follows.

Denote $S$ as the random sum in question. We may assume that $S$ is sum of a partial $k$-permutation from $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ chosen at random. The probability of choosing any $k$-permutation is $\frac{1}{A_n^k} = \frac{(n-k)!}{n!}$. Our goal is to calculate $\mathbb E S^2$, as then trivially $\mathbb DS = \mathbb E S^2 - (\mathbb E S)^2$ and the $\mathbb E S$ part is calculated in the accepted answer.

By definition we write
$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\mathbb ES^2 = \sum_{\sigma} (\sigma_1 + \ldots + \sigma_k)^2 = \sum_{\sigma} \sum_{i=1}^k \sigma_i^2 + 2\sum_{\sigma}\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \sum_{j = i+1}^k \sigma_i \sigma_j$$
where $\sum\limits_{\sigma}$ runs over all the $k$-permutations of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. The second "$=$" is due to the algebraic expansion of $(\sum a_i)^2$.
Before we deal with the first sum, we state an observation.

**Observation 1.** For any $i$
$$\sum\limits_\sigma \sigma_i^2 = \frac{n!}{n(n-k)!} (1^2 + \ldots + n^2).$$

**Proof.** Note that all terms in the sum $\sum\limits_\sigma \sigma_i^2$ are equally frequent. That is, there are as many terms equal to $p^2$ as there are terms equal to $q^2$ for any $p, q$. Since there are $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ terms in the sum, any term $p^2$ appears $\frac{n!}{n(n-k)!}$ times, and so the conclusion is straightforward. $\blacksquare$

So for the first sum we have
$$\sum\limits_\sigma \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \sigma_i^2 
= \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \sum\limits_\sigma \sigma_i^2 = k \cdot \frac{n!}{n(n-k)!} \cdot \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \cdot \frac{k(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$

We proceed to evaluate the second sum $\sum\limits_\sigma \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} \sum\limits_{j=i+1}^k \sigma_i \sigma_j$. We note a similar observation.

**Observation 2.** For any $i$, $j$
$$\sum\limits_\sigma \sigma_i \sigma_j = \frac{1}{(n-1)n} \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \sum_{p, q = 1; p \neq q}^n pq.$$

**Proof.** In the same fashion, we observe that any product $pq$ of an *ordered* pair $(p, q)$ is encountered in the sum as frequently as any other term. Since there are $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ terms in the sum, and there are $n(n-1)$ ordered pairs possible, we conclude that any term $pq$, where $p \neq q$, is encountered $\frac{1}{n(n-1)} \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ times, hence follows the observation. $\blacksquare$

We now must do a not so difficult calculation:

$$\sum_{p,q=1; p\neq q}^n pq = \sum_{p=1}^n \sum_{q=1}^n pq - \sum_{p=1}^n p^2 = \sum_{p=1}^n p \sum_{q=1}^n q - \sum_{p=1}^n p^2 = \left (\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right)^2 - \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \frac{n(n+1)(n-1)(3n+2)}{12},$$

and so we can see that
$$\sum\limits_\sigma \sigma_i \sigma_j = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \cdot \frac{(n+1)(3n+2)}{12}.$$

The second sum $\sum\limits_\sigma \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} \sum\limits_{j=i+1}^k \sigma_i \sigma_j$ then becomes

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} \sum\limits_{j=i+1}^k \sum\limits_\sigma \sigma_i \sigma_j = \frac{k(k-1)}{2} \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \cdot \frac{(n+1)(3n+2)}{12}.$$

We are ready to calculate the sum in question. Just plug all the results to get

$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \mathbb E S^2 = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \left[ \frac{k (n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + 2 \cdot \frac{k(k-1)}{2} \cdot \frac{(n+1)(3n+2)}{12} \right].$$

We divide by $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$, factor out $\frac{k(n+1)}{6}$, and arrive at
$$\mathbb E S^2 = \frac{k(n+1)}{6} \left( 2n+1 + \frac{(k-1)(3n+2)}{2} \right)$$

Finally, the formula for variance $\mathbb DS = \mathbb ES^2 - (\mathbb ES)^2$  yields
$$\mathbb DS = \frac{k(n+1)}{6} \left( 2n+1 + \frac{(k-1)(3n+2)}{2} \right) - k^2 \cdot \frac{(n+1)^2}{4} = \frac{k(n+1)(n-k)}{12}.$$

Answer (score 1):

This problem gets simpler when generalized.  Let $X = \{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$, and let $S_k$ be the sum of $k$ elements chosen uniformly at random from $X$ without replacement.  Then $\mathbb{E}[S_k] = k \bar{x}$ by the linearity of expectation, where $\bar{x}$ is the mean of $X$.

The variance $\mathrm{var}[S_k]$ is a symmetric polynomial of degree $2$ in the variables $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$.  Therefore it has the form $a p_1^2 + b p_2$ where $$p_j \doteq \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^j.$$  We may determine the constants $a$ and $b$ by evaluating $\mathrm{var}[S_k]$ for two cases.  When $x_i = 1$ for all $i$, $\mathrm{var}[S_k] = 0$, and $p_1 = p_2 = n$.  When $x_1 = 1$ and $x_i = 0$ for $i>1$, $S_k$ has a Bernoulli distribution with $p = k/n$, so $\mathrm{var}[S_k] = p(1-p) = k(n-k)/n^2$, whereas $p_1 = p_2 = 1$.  Therefore, $$
a n^2 + b n = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad
a + b = \frac{k(n-k)}{n^2}.
$$
Solving for $a$ and $b$ yields the result$$
\mathrm{var}[S_k] = \frac{k(n-k)}{n^2(n-1)}\left(n p_2 - p_1^2\right) = \frac{k(n-k)}{n}s^2,
$$
where $s^2$ is the sample variance of $X$.  In particular, $s^2 = n(n+1)/12$ for $x_i = i$, so the solution to the original problem is$$
\mathrm{var}[S_k] = \frac{k(n-k)(n+1)}{12},
$$
in agreement with dnes's answer.